# Disable notification for declined calls

Tags: notifications, calls, htc-wildfire

I have a HTC WildFire (android 2.1) phone. I want to disable the notifications for the calls I knowingly decline. I still want to get the notification for the calls I miss. Does anyone know any setting/app to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing the back button when you get an incoming call - that usually makes the caller continue listening to a ringing tone but the ringing on your phone stops.

Pressing the reject / call end button will make the ringing stop as well as cut the call for the caller.

If you'd rather stop the ringing / vibration but still want to answer the call after a few seconds (like walking out of a noisy room etc.), press any volume key on the side.

Comment: My requirement is slightly different. When I decline a call I get a notification in the notification bar for a missed call. I don't want to get the notification as I have knowingly declined the call. Currently, I have to unlock the phone and clear the notification bar after I decline the call. Otherwise, the LED keeps flashing which is kind of annoying.

Comment: Well, you Wildfire's behaviour is different to my Samsung Spica's. In my case, i don't get a notification when i decline a call, either via the END key or the BACK key. YMMV.